# A path below the nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-path

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz,twemojis}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Nodes:
    \node (s) at (-2,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node (a1) at (-1, 2) {\twemoji{art}};
    \node [opacity=0.2] (e) at (2,0) {$\star$};

    % Paths:
    \draw [->] plot coordinates {(s) (e)}; 
    \draw[blue,dashed,->] plot[smooth,tension=0.5, left] coordinates  {(s) (a1) (e)};
    % \node (a1) at (-1, 2) {\twemoji{art}}; ===> Reprint the node.
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image]

As you can see the line is **above** the art icon.
There is a way to do it without reprint the node? (or define a new node).

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's possible, inside a scope, with the `background` library.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @SebGlav, here is the solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz,twemojis}
\usetikzlibrary {backgrounds} % <== Add this.

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Nodes:
    \node (s) at (-2,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node (a1) at (-1, 2) {\twemoji{art}};
    \node [opacity=0.2] (e) at (2,0) {$\star$};

    % Paths:
    \scoped [on background layer] { % <== And this line.
        \draw [->] plot coordinates {(s) (e)}; 
        \draw[blue,dashed,->] plot[smooth,tension=0.5, left] coordinates  {(s) (a1) (e)};
    }%
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Exactly! Didn't have enough time to answer, you did it well +1